# errors=n in sql loader

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sql-loader

I would like to know the significance of ERRORS=n in a control file. 
Can we use this option to fail the SQL loader if it crosses a particular value(101 or higher in this case)?
How can I handle the exit status from the failed scenario in Unix?
What happens to SQL loader when it reaches the number of errors?

Consider the below example :

```
SQLLDR CONTROL=sample.ctl, LOG=sample.log, BAD=baz.bad, DATA=etc.dat 
USERID=scott/tiger, ERRORS=100, LOAD=2000, DISCARD=toss.dsc,
DISCARDMAX=5
```

Comment: Give it a try!  It's trivial to set up an example. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation : [**SQL* Loader**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm)

For UNIX, the exit codes are as follows:

```
ALL ROWS LOADED SUCCESSFULLY                                    0
ALL OR SOME ROWS REJECTED                                       2
ALL OR SOME ROWS DISCARDED                                      2
DISCONTINUED LOAD                                               2
COMMAND-LINE OR SYNTAX ERRORS                                   1
ORACLE ERRORS NONRECOVERABLE FOR SQL*LOADER                     1
OPERATING SYSTEM ERRORS (SUCH AS FILE OPEN/CLOSE AND MALLOC)    1
```

So, you can use the return code in Unix using the `$?` operator after the execution of `sqlldr` and use it in your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
SQLLDR CONTROL=sample.ctl, LOG=sample.log, BAD=baz.bad, DATA=etc.dat 
USERID=scott/tiger, ERRORS=100, LOAD=2000, DISCARD=toss.dsc,
DISCARDMAX=5
exit_code=$?
if [[ ${exit_code} -ne 0 ]] 
then
  echo "Failed"
  #The commands to run for failed scenario.
  #...
fi
```

Comment: The exit_code assignment can be written more simply as `exit_code=$?`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what it is meant for.  See this Oracle [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm).

> ```
> errors -- number of errors to allow            (Default 50)
> ```

SQL loader will stop loading if the number of errors exceed this.  Setting `errors=0` will make the loader ignore all errors.

Comment: It just stops the load or it makes the entire load as failure. Does it return any SQL Loader error to Unix in this case?

Comment: If you look slightly further down in that same doc, it gives the Unix exit codes that it returns. The only time it returns 0 is if all rows load successfully.

Comment: From the manual: "To permit no errors at all, set ERRORS=0. To specify that all errors be allowed, use a very high number. "